# Firebase REST API 401 unauthorized for everyone but me

Tags: javascript, rest, firebase-realtime-database, oauth, google-api-js-client

I'm using firebase's real time database to store data, and I have permission rules set to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to read and write to the database using rest/fetch, and it seems to be working fine. But after some investigation, it seems it only works for me specifically, and other users receive a `401 unauthorized` response. My code looks like

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, (token) => {
    let url = this.url + `users/${id}.json?access_token=${token}`;
    const headers = new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    });

    fetch(url, { headers: headers })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json();
      })
  });
```

Token is obtained by calling `getAuthToken` from the extensions background page. id is found by calling `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo`:

```
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo((info) => {
      email = info.email;
      userId = info.id;
    });
```

I also have the following scope, which I thought would enable reading and writing from firebase: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore`

Any ideas? I'm very confused why it would work, but only for me.

Comment: This probably depends on how the variables `id` and `token` are initialized. Can you edit your question to show that? --- Note that the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore` has nothing to do with Firebase **Realtime Database**.

Comment: Thanks for the input Frank, I've updated the question with how I'm obtaining `id` and `token`. Is my method here not correct? Appreciate the help

Comment: I answered with my best guess of what's going on below, so let's follow up there 

Comment: Hey @JesseSliter. Any updates?

Comment: Apologies for the slow reply. I'm 95% sure your answer is correct and that I need to refactor my code to use firebase auth. I just havent gotten around to it yet. I'll go ahead and mark your reply as the accepted answer in the mean time and change it if for whatever reason its not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Firebase documentation on [generating an access token to access the Realtime Database REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#generate_an_access_token):

> generate a Google OAuth2 access token with the following required scopes:
>
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database

Most likely you're missing that second scope.

Note by the way that this will grant you full administrative access to the database, and will not follow your security rules. These people are essentially collaborators on your project: they can either see/edit all data, or they cannot.

To allow a user access to the database *and* follow the security rules, the user will have to sign in with Firebase Authentication, and you'll have to pass their ID token to the REST API.