# FCM HTTP v1 API return 403

Tags: java, firebase

I migrated to use Google's new FCM HTTP v1 api and today the messages are sent normally. But I have a problem, sometimes, without explanation, I receive status code 403 for some messages. All the settings are ok, the service is active, the authentication token is ok and I don't know why these few messages per day return 403.
Would anyone have any tips?

Here is my code that sends it:

```
try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
    String urlFinal = FCM_URL.replace("nomeprojeto", Projetos.getProjetoId(keyStore));
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlFinal);
    // Set headers
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAccessToken(keyStore));
    // Json generation
    Root mensagem = new Root();
    mensagem.message.notification = msg.notification;
    mensagem.message.token = msg.token;
    mensagem.message.data = msg.data;
    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(mensagem);
    //System.out.println(json);
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, "UTF-8"));
    // Call http
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    // Validate response.
    if (statusCode == 200) {
        pushBean.log(msg, keyStore);
        System.out.println("push processado - " + new Date());
        return;
    }
    if (statusCode == 404) {
        // documentação indica para não retentar no 400 e 404
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/scale-fcm?hl=pt-br
        String error = statusCode + " - Token FCM não encontrado: " + msg.token;
        pushBean.logErro(msg, keyStore, error + msg.token);
        return;
    }
    if (statusCode == 403) {
        // documentação indica para não retentar no 403
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/scale-fcm?hl=pt-br
        String error = "403 - Token FCM não aceito: " + msg.token;
        pushBean.logErro(msg, keyStore, error + msg.token);
        return;
    }
    if (statusCode != 200) {
        String error = "Erro ao efetuar envio do FCM, código do retorno = %d";
        error = String.format(error, statusCode);
        FCMException ex = new FCMException(error);
        throw ex;
    }
```

Below is the returned error JSON 403:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "SenderId mismatch",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "SENDER_ID_MISMATCH"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: Post code so someone can start guessing.  But 403 means it got the message but didn't auth it, so perhaps a timeout is happening in your giant batch that causes this issue.  If you only do 500 per hour does it still have the issue?  It could also be hitting your API package submissions limit per hour?

Comment: It is not bath processing. My code sends one message at a time.

Comment: Does it error on the same type of request or can you find anything different with the offending request?  Perhaps you are hitting the thresholds allowed per hour?

Comment: So far I can't find any difference from other messages that are being successfully delivered. It seems random to me, some return 403. Wouldn't there be a problem with the mobile token? [msg.token]

Comment: I did some tests and discovered that authentication error is returned 401. In my case, these few messages are returned with 403 indicating something that I don't know how to resolve.

Comment: Check this article on 401 issue with Firebase :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70946138/firebase-rest-api-401-unauthorized-for-everyone-but-me

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/ErrorCode?hl=pt-br